# Trying to turn a json string into a JArray

Tags: c#, json, json.net

For the past 3 hours i have been trying to search for a solution on how to convert a json string into a JArray to return to another method

The string is this

```
{\"item1\":[{\"id\":\"61578ba2ce16422d8d0a728d\",\"key\":\"TEMP-4BIYFUWSJEKPZMBHR98YXXU9\",\"type\":2,\"status\":0,\"name\":null,\"email\":\"gewqgwgswgweg@gmail.com\",\"online\":false,\"renewal\":null,\"rentalEnd\":null,\"lastBound\":null,\"lastOnline\":\"2021-10-02T17:42:41.54Z\",\"expiry\":\"2021-10-02T22:28:49.992Z\"}],\"item2\":{\"id\":\"61578afe0f17e199f3938758\",\"firstName\":\"gewqg\",\"lastName\":\"wgswgweg\",\"email\":\"gewqgwgswgweg@gmail.com\",\"phoneNumber\":null,\"image\":null,\"apiKeys\":[],\"discord\":null,\"lastOnline\":\"2021-10-02T18:28:58.363Z\",\"twoFactorEnabled\":true,\"claims\":[{\"claimType\":\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role\",\"claimValue\":\"User\"}]}}
```

i have tried many things e.g. DeserializeObject and use JArray.parse but that dosent work
and on the web there is no solution for this

the method is down below

```
    public JArray test()
    {
       string test = jsonstringabove;
       return somehowreturnasjarray
    }
```

if anyone has any idea on how i would do this please let me know because i am completely stuck

Comment: "That doesn't work" - error? exception? wrong output? what exactly doesn't work? can you post the code for what you did please?

Comment: one of the things i tried that i saw online 

            JObject myjson = JObject.Parse(test);
            int count = getCountMyJson(myjson);
            JArray nameArray = new JArray();
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                if (myjson[i + ""] != null)
                    nameArray.Add(myjson[i + ""]);
            }
            return nameArray;

Comment: another solution that failed

            var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JArray>(test);
            return obj;

Comment: and the last one that also failed

            var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(test);
            string jsonArray = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response);
            JArray data = (JArray)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonArray);
            return data;

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary , the solution is very obvious, no further info is needed on this excellent question

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON string is not an array of items so cannot be deserialised into a [`JArray`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JArray.htm).

You will need to deserialise your JSON to a concrete class or a `JObject` to extract data from it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you not using `DeserializeObject` because of `Item1` and `Item2`? which will  generate new class, for example class Item1{..} class Item2{} ?
In that case have you tried using `System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject`

```
string jsonstring = "{\"item1\":[{\"id\":\"61578ba2ce16422d8d0a728d\",\"key\":\"TEMP-4BIYFUWSJEKPZMBHR98YXXU9\",\"type\":2,\"status\":0,\"name\":null,\"email\":\"gewqgwgswgweg@gmail.com\",\"online\":false,\"renewal\":null,\"rentalEnd\":null,\"lastBound\":null,\"lastOnline\":\"2021-10-02T17:42:41.54Z\",\"expiry\":\"2021-10-02T22:28:49.992Z\"}],\"item2\":{\"id\":\"61578afe0f17e199f3938758\",\"firstName\":\"gewqg\",\"lastName\":\"wgswgweg\",\"email\":\"gewqgwgswgweg@gmail.com\",\"phoneNumber\":null,\"image\":null,\"apiKeys\":[],\"discord\":null,\"lastOnline\":\"2021-10-02T18:28:58.363Z\",\"twoFactorEnabled\":true,\"claims\":[{\"claimType\":\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role\",\"claimValue\":\"User\"}]}}";           
dynamic data = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject>(jsonstring);
foreach (var datum in data)
{
    var itemObject = (KeyValuePair<string, object>)datum;
    var valuesList = (List<object>)itemObject.Value;
    foreach (var val in valuesList)
    {
        var itemVal = (IDictionary<string, object>)val;
        var item = new { id = itemVal["id"], key = itemVal["key"], name = itemVal["name"], type = itemVal["type"] };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand the problem correctly. Please note that your items Item1 and Item2 are structured differently according to the Json.

You could do the following.

```
public class Root
{
    [JsonExtensionData]
    public IDictionary<string,JToken> Items{get;set;}

    [JsonIgnore]
    public JArray ItemArray => new JArray(Items.Values);
}

var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(str);
var arrayResult = result.ItemArray;
```